# How to insert an image in wpf path?

Tags: wpf, path

Hi i using the following code to create a path in WPF.

```
        <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="200,200" Point2="0,400" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
```

It works fine. Now what i need is to have an image in between a path. So that the image would lie in the center of the curved line. Could you please help of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Fill Property

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill">
    <Path.Data>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Image.jpg"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```